# Use Excel AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy to append data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function which copies data from a data sheet and pastes it into the sheet within which it is called. Please see below:

```
Public Sub Barry()

    Const DATA = "data!a1"
    Const OUTPUT = "a3:c3"
    Const FILTER_VALUE_ADDRESS = "d1"
    Const FILTER_COLUMN = 4

    Dim rCrit As Range, rData As Range

    Set rData = Range(DATA).CurrentRegion
    Set rCrit = rData.Resize(2, 1).Offset(, rData.Columns.Count + 2)
    rCrit(1) = rData(1, FILTER_COLUMN): rCrit(2) = Range(FILTER_VALUE_ADDRESS)
    rData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rCrit, Range(OUTPUT)
    rCrit.Clear

End Sub
```

Now it works like a charm however I would like a user to be able to call this method multiple times **by clicking a button which has a macro assigned** and keep appending data within the current sheet, albeit with one blank row between them.

Using the method above, I can't workout how this is possible.

Comment: And how do you want to allow user to use this method multiple times? I don't see a problem here could you specify?

Comment: I've added that in as a comment. The problem is that the current code will replace all contents below a3:c3 within columns a and c

Comment: So If I understand correctly, you want to keep the old data from previous filters and add the new from the current sort to the bottom of the list every time the button is pushed?

Comment: @ScottCraner you've got it in one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign this routine to the button:

```
Public Sub Barry2()

    Const DATA = "data!a1"
    Const OUTPUT = "a3:c3"
    Const FILTER_VALUE_ADDRESS = "d1"
    Const FILTER_COLUMN = 4

    Dim rCrit As Range, rData As Range, rOut As Range

    Set rData = Range(DATA).CurrentRegion
    Set rCrit = rData.Resize(2, 1).Offset(, rData.Columns.Count + 2)
    rCrit(1) = rData(1, FILTER_COLUMN): rCrit(2) = Range(FILTER_VALUE_ADDRESS)

    With ActiveSheet.Range(OUTPUT)
        Set rOut = .Offset(.Item(.Parent.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 2)
    End With
    rOut = Range(OUTPUT).Value

    rData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rCrit, rOut
    rOut.Delete xlUp

    rCrit.Clear

End Sub
```

Note: it is important that the three column headers in row 3 of the SUMMARY sheet exist before this is run.

Comment: Actually I tell a lie @Excel Hero as I had to use 

Set rOut = Range(OUTPUT).Offset(Range(OUTPUT).CurrentRegion.rows.Count - 1).

It seemed that a blank line was added after every paste. Guessing the rOut.Delete xlUp didn't work.

Comment: Bizarrely the additional line break was welcomed (although not asked for hehe) however it then meant that additional data could not be appended

Comment: If you want the line break it is no problem. Just let me know and I'll update.

Comment: @BarryBlade Please double-check. I have again and it works as advertised.

Comment: Yep totally sure. Could we try with the line break in. That is my ideal solution and I can update my question to reflect this.

Comment: Yes. I'll work it up now for the line break. Not to belabor the point, but I had updated the answer a few moments after first posting it. The code changed. Have you been using the latest posted code in your testing? Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: At any rate, the answer has been updated now to provide ONE blank row between runs in the output.

Comment: Works perfectly! 2/2 indeed!